# C++ Raii and stack unwinding

Tags: c++, scope, raii

(I modified the original question to be more meaningful)

With respect to return statement, are Raii object destroyed before/after/between return statement?

for example

```
size_t advance() {
    boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    return value_++;  // is lock destroyed after increment?
}
```

thank you

Comment: What reason do have for thinking they are not?

Comment: @Neil I do not per se, however I do not know mechanics of return statements well enough to be completely sure.  So just wanted to confirm

Comment: Make it interesting: use value_ / 0;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your modified question, given the code:

```
return X;
```

X will always be evaluated before the return takes place. Then what happens is equivalent to all the nested scopes of the function being exited, in order from inmost to outmost, with destructors being called appropriately at each exit.

Answer (score 1):

You can test this easily by writing your own simple class with a destructor, e.g.

```
class X
   {
   public:
      ~X() { std::cout << "X::destructor" << std::endl;
   }

size_t advance()
   {
   X x;
   return value++;
   }
```

Put a break in the destructor of X, and see if value has already been incremented at that moment.  You may also try to compile using /FA (Visual Studio) and see which assembly is generated by the compiler.

Comment: so, stack is unwound (hope its correct word) after return statement?

Comment: I would expect this, but to be sure, you have to try it.

Comment: "try it" is the worst way to check up on a language feature. Th C++ Standard says that x will be destroyed when the return is encountered - any compiler that emitted code that didn't do this would not be a C++ compiler.

Comment: @Neil, I agree, but C++ has quite some subtleties it can be easier to just try it instead of guessing what is intended in the C++ standard.  I also think that it can be more 'therapeutical' to try it yourself.  It's easier to remember something if you tried it yourself rather than something you read in a book.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - they are equivalent. Lock is destroyed after increment. Otherwise you would have the same problem with the later case.